# Bison: yywrap() to parse same file exactly one more time?

Tags: parsing, bison, flex-lexer

I have some data consisting of numbers that I would like to parse with `Bison` after lexing with `Flex`. To do so I need to know the minimum and maximum of all my numbers - if I cheat and explicitly define these, I can do it.

I know I must eventually automatically find the maximum of all lines before I run the parser function for the first.

I thought I would use `yywrap()` but it does not return to the start.

Here is my `yywrap()`: it returns `0` once and then `1`, but does not seem to return to the start in between. It remains at the end, and my test `printf`(s) appear side-by-side there.-

```
int wrap;
int yywrap()
{
if (wrap == 0) {wrap++;return 0;}
else {return 1;}
}
```

Currently
**INPUT**:

```
--
G0
G0
G0
e0
--
--
--
--
F0
F0
F0
D0
--
--
--
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
------------
67----------
67----------
67----------
--------63--
------------
------------
------------
------------
----65------
----65------
----65------
----------62
------------
------------
------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Generated-Scanner.html#index-yywrap_0028_0029) has this to say about using `yywrap` (emphasis added):

> When the scanner receives an end-of-file indication from `YY_INPUT`, it then checks the `yywrap()` function. If `yywrap()` returns false (zero), then **it is assumed that the function has gone ahead and set up `yyin` to point to another input file**, and scanning continues. If it returns true (non-zero), then the scanner terminates, returning 0 to its caller. Note that in either case, the start condition remains unchanged; it does not revert to `INITIAL`.

So if you want to [`rewind(yyin)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rewind.3p.html), you need to do so yourself, in the `yywrap` function.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the question edit! You correctly point out that I had my 0 and 1 reversed. I will make use of the rewind.

Comment: @user240254: i think your 0 and 1 are fine. In fact, you could reduce it to `int yywrap(void){ rewind(yyin); return wrap++; }` although that's not the most readable.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought my little temporary cheats were still in effect. Do you think that manual page should mention rewind?

Comment: @user240254: No, it's not a common use case. The manual clearly states that `yywrap` must prepare `yyin` for the following invocation of `YY_INPUT`; normally that means opening a new file but there might not even be files. (You can use the `yywrap` mechanism to sequence through fixed strings, or generated code, or whatever.) On the whole, parsing the same input twice is not very common, and IMHO a robust program which really needs to read twice should make a copy the first time in case the input stream is not repeatable. But I wasn't going to say that in my answer.

Comment: Having said that, I have no connection with the flex project or its manual :-)